# Correct way to phrase something that varies by type and degree

Tags: phrases

In the first instance, what are the grammatically correct ways to phrase the statement below?
Second, if more than one is correct, which one seems the more appropriate or natural-sounding?

> Typhoons [differ/vary] [in/by] the degree and variety of damage (they
>   cause)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the variants using the preposition *in* here, with either of the verbs.

I'd probably choose 'vary' to suggest a difference really in scale rather than kind.